# MySQL Create Table with current date appended to table name

Tags: mysql

Im looking to run a create table statement but give it a name based on the current timestamp.
I need the name of the table to resemble something like this: **2020_07_23_new_table**

I thought something like this would work, but Im not certain if this is best practice:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%y_%m_%d'), '_new_table') LIKE old_table
);
```

Is there a way to accomplish this within MySQL?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's generally a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can use a dynamic query. Something like below.

```
SET @SQL = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y_%m_%d'), '_new_table LIKE OLD_TABLE');
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[***Check Demo Here***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e9e251a5110fb958c2b739b76b0d1c16)

Comment: Hi Arun, this is exactly what I was looking for. Quick question, how would I create an insert for this created table? Meaning what would the format look like? Eg. ```INSERT INTO new_table_timestamp SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE id = ?"```

Comment: Your `Insert` statement looks good. Are you facing any issues with that? If you want to insert all the rows remove the `where` clause @ZQuilboar14

Comment: Also if this solution solved your problem please accept the answer by clicking the `tick` mark so that other users will understand that this question is resolved. @ZQuilboar14